# PayPal Payments Pro Hosted Solution No Cart/Item Description

Tags: paypal

I've successfully got a payments pro implementation working.

But none of the fields PayPal lists as accepting (in their documentation) allow me to specify a `Description` value for the payment. As a result, when a person pays by PayPal account and receives a PayPal emailed 'receipt' (despite my PayPal Pro settings set to NOT have PayPal send any receipts) there is a blank under `Description`.

Are there some fields other than the ones listed in the documentation? Here's the link to the docs I'm working with:
https://www.paypalobjects.com/webstatic/en_GB/developer/docs/pdf/hostedsolution_uk.pdf